# Why is the address bar at the bottom in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, samba, gui

In Ubuntu 16.04 I could connect to a server using a slightly annoying but workable "Connect to Server" option. Now it has changed to "Other Locations" and when you open it there is not discernible way to connect to a known server.

Once you've noticed that they have foolishly put the address bar at the BOTTOM of the window it is impossible. Once you have noticed that it is merely significantly harder than the previous release.

Comment: We're not the devs.

Comment: I feel your pain. The whole trend towards unusable but minimalistically pretty user interfaces is absolutely awful. However, this isn't the right place to discuss it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

The `Other locations` option was created to compliment the left pane of Nautilus. When there are too many items to fit in the left pane they can be placed in a brand new window.

This story describes benefits of `Other locations` in more detail: [other-locations-on-nautilus-gsoc-final-report/](https://feaneron.com/2015/08/21/other-locations-on-nautilus-gsoc-final-report/)

A tutorial to connect via SSH and `Enter Location` from new drop down menu is described here: [files-connect-server-ssh/](https://fedoramagazine.org/files-connect-server-ssh/) A screen capture is provided to show the `New Location` feature.

[image: Nautilus Enter Location]

Comment: Thanks for the info. From that blog I can see that the small monitor use case was carefully considered. On my big monitor, things that I used before without even thinking about where to find the were now really not obvious at all.